# RxJS server polling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, observable, observer-pattern

I need to poll the server and update data on the client side. For that I have a dispatcher that dispatches an action that is called `FRONT_PAGE`. The action is dispatched once the app starts and the client should send requests twice a second. The requests are being sent but I am getting the following error.

```js
×
TypeError: Object(...)(...) is not a function
Observable.pipe
A:src/internal/Observable.ts:439
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
doInnerSub
A:internal/operators/mergeInternals.ts:71
outerNext
A:internal/operators/mergeInternals.ts:53
  50 |         }
  51 |     }));
  52 | };
> 53 | source.subscribe(new OperatorSubscriber(subscriber, outerNext, function () {
     | ^  54 |     isComplete = true;
  55 |     checkComplete();
  56 | }));
```

The code.

```js
import { from, of, timer } from 'rxjs'
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { FRONT_PAGE } from './constants'

const poll_server = url => {
    timer(0, 500)
        .pipe(from(fetch(url))
            .pipe((x) => { console.log("Polling server.."); return x })
            .pipe(map(response => response.json())))
}

export const server_dispatch = action => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FRONT_PAGE: {
            poll_server('http://localhost:8080/warnings')
        }
        default:
            return of(action)
    }
}
```

the end point

```js
app.get('/warnings', (req, res) => {
    console.log("[GET] /warnings")
    const baseline = req.query.baseline ?? -1
    if (version > baseline) {
        res.send(warnings(alerts.filter(a => a.prediction)))
    } else if (game) {
        res.status(204).send({})
    } else {
        res.status(404).send();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** `poll_server` is a function that has almsot no effects and then returns nothing/void.

For example:

```ts
// return arg + 1
const lambdaFunction = arg => arg + 1;

// returns nothing
const lambdaFunction = arg => {arg + 1;};

// return arg + 1
const lambdaFunction = arg => {return arg + 1;};
```

---

**2.** `.pipe(from(fetch(url)).pipe(...` What are you attempting here?

`from` not is not a pipeable operator. You can use it to create an observable from a promise, observableLike, or iterator. Not as a composable operator.

---

**3.** The following actually works because operators are actually just functions (hens why they can be composed so well!). So the identity function here is fine, but I'm pretty sure it's not doing what you think it is.

```ts
.pipe((x) => { console.log("Polling server.."); return x })
```

`console.log("Polling server..")` will be run before your observable is subscribed to. In case this, your observable here is never subscribed to (as it's never returned), but I imagine you might see "Polling server.." in the console anyway.

---

**4.**

```ts
.pipe(x => { console.log("Polling server.."); return x })
.pipe(map(response => response.json())))
```

is the same as:

```ts
.pipe(
  x => { console.log("Polling server.."); return x },
  map(response => response.json())
)
```

That's because the chaining applications is the same thing as composition.

---

**5.** `server_dispatch` only return an observable for the default case in the switch. Otherwise it returns `undefined`. Is that really the behavior you want?

Comment: The behavior I want is to update the data once a time using rxjs. The data is updated on the server once a time and I want the data to be updated once it's updated on the server.